# Просмотр дерева элементов

Tags: python, lxml

С помощью cssselect нахожу элемент и вывожу его для отладки с помощью print.
Например:

```
search_result_container = left_panel.cssselect('#search_result_container > div:not([class])')[0]
```

В результате показывается найденный элемент.

```
<Element div at 0x15e01f988b8>
```

Как можно посмотреть полностью его дерево? В Beautiful Soup 4 при выводе print, оно выводится автоматически

Comment: print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)), где root - это ваш элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `etree.tostring`:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '<a><b/><c><z>Тест</z><h/></c></a>'

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
print(root)
print()

print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
print()

print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode'))
print()

print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```

Консоль:

```
<Element a at 0x2d82448>

b'<a>\n  <b/>\n  <c>\n    <z>&#1058;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090;</z>\n    <h/>\n  </c>\n</a>\n'
<a>
  <b/>
  <c>
    <z>Тест</z>
    <h/>
  </c>
</a>


<a>
  <b/>
  <c>
    <z>Тест</z>
    <h/>
  </c>
</a>


<a><b/><c><z>Тест</z><h/></c></a>
```